# npm run build failed without module `./color/shorten-hsl`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

```
Error: Cannot find module './color/shorten-hsl'
  Require stack:
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-1\value-optimizers\color.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-1\value-optimizers.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\configuration.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\properties\populate-components.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\properties\merge-into-shorthands.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\properties\optimize.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\merge-adjacent.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\optimize.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\clean-css\index.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\html-minifier-terser\src\htmlminifier.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\index.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  - C:\Users\progr\Documents\GitHub\typing-speed-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\build.js

  - loader:1075 Module._resolveFilename
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15

  - loader:920 Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27

  - loader:1141 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19

  - helpers:110 require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18

  - color.js:2 Object.<anonymous>
    [typing-speed-app]/[clean-css]/lib/optimizer/level-1/value-optimizers/color.js:2:18

  - loader:1254 Module._compile
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14

  - loader:1308 Module._extensions..js
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10

  - loader:1117 Module.load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32

  - loader:958 Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12

  - loader:1141 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19
```

I keep getting this error while trying to build my program using `npm run build`. I installed `color` using `npm i color` in a clueless attempt to solve it, but it didn't work.

My **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "^0.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "color": "^4.2.3",
    "color-convert": "^2.0.1",
    "firebase": "^9.23.0",
    "identicon.js": "^2.3.3",
    "random-words": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  }
}
```

Node, React, and everything are installed very recently, so unless there are such a breaking change in the recent week I should have noticed earlier

**Ps**: `npm start` works for me perfectly.
**PPS**: I tried to delete `node_modules`, reinstall all using `npm install` but did not work